# How to download DataExplorer queries?

Tags: discussion, data-dump

I'm trying to collect (SQL query, description) pairs for a project and the queries here https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries seem very useful. Is there any way to automatically retrieve them? (I can't seem to find them in the StackExchange dump https://archive.org/details/stackexchange)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way to get all those queries automatically (and I doubt it is useful as a feature).

You could do the following:

- make a HTTP GET request on `http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries?order_by=everything`. Get all the query links out and call them (on `.title h3 a @href`);
- Determine the place the query is stored and retrieve the query from it (this is a little hard since it is formatted. You could take all the `#text` elements from inside `queryBodyText`). Or a better option: get the `id` from the link in the previous step, then call the `fork` URL (`http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/fork/12345`) and get the text from element with id `sql`;
- Store the title and query in your own database or file.